# How do I prove that this function is an antiderivative?

Tags: integration, analysis, differential-forms

I have the following question:

> Let $f,g\in C^1(\Bbb{R}^2)$ s.t. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$. Show that $$F(x,y)=\int_0^x f(s,0)~ds+\int_0^y g(x,t)~dt$$is an antiderivative of the $1$-form $\omega=f(x,y)~dx+g(x,y)~dy$.

So for me it is clear that I want to show that $dF=\omega$. Therefore I first wanted to compute $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int_0^x f(s,0)~ds +\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_0^y g(x,t)~dt$. Now the only point where I have questions is $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int_0^x f(s,0)~ds$$ then I wanted to use the main criteria of analysis and get $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int_0^x f(s,0)~ds=f(x,0)-f(0,0)$$ but somehow they left $f(0,0)$ away and I don't know why one can do this, why do we know that $f(0,0)=0$?

But the rest is clear to me.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus reads $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)\, dt = f(x),$$not "$f(x)-f(a)$."

Comment: Ah yes sure only if I would have $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x)dx =f(b)-f(a)$$ right?

Comment: @aprozz No... $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is a constant, so its derivative is zero. I think you mean that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)$, where $F' = f$.

Comment: Ah sure yes my mistake! thanks

Comment: Ironically, the rest is the subtle part.

Comment: Yes the rest ist clear thanks